# Add new properties to an array of objects from another array with different lengths so once the array is done iterating, it starts from first again

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I would like to merge two array of objects. They basically have different keys but I would like to merge the keys of second array with that of the first one. How do I achieve this?

```
  $scope.links = [
    {
      name: 'JRD',
      status: 'active'
    },
    {
      name: 'JRM',
      status: 'active'
    },
    {
      name: 'JRH',
      status: 'active'
    }
  ];

  $scope.colors = [
        {
            color: 'red',
            value: '#f00'
        },
        {
            color: 'green',
            value: '#0f0'
        },
        {
            color: 'blue',
            value: '#00f'
        },
        {
            color: 'cyan',
            value: '#0ff'
        },
        {
            color: 'magenta',
            value: '#f0f'
        },
        {
            color: 'yellow',
            value: '#ff0'
        },
    ];
```

I want to combine these two to achieve a merged array like this below.

```
[
    {
      name: 'JRD',
      status: 'active',
      color: 'red',
      value: '#f00'
    },
    {
      name: 'JRM',
      status: 'active',
      color: 'green',
      value: '#0f0'
    },
    {
      name: 'JRH',
      status: 'active',
      color: 'blue',
      value: '#00f'
    }
  ];
```

Can I use reduce or forEach to achieve the same? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the merge logic? How do you know which  items to merge? How to you handle the case where the two arrays are not the same length?

Comment: So its like joining those elements into the main array.

Comment: Yes, but HOW? Those arrays are different lengths and could contain any number of items.How do you decide which items to merge, and which not to merge?

Comment: Yeah, So if the color array is iterated wholly, it should repeat from first. So if yellow is added to first array, then starts from red again.

Comment: I would ADD THAT TO THE ORIGINAL question, instead of having to make people search through the comments

Comment: Sorry. Will do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can `map` `$scope.links` into the new array using the modulo operator `%` to stay within the bounds of `$scope.colors` and use `Object.assign` to merge the objects once you got them, like so:

```
var merged = $scope.links.map(function(link, index) {
    return Object.assign({}, link, $scope.colors[index % $scope.colors.length]);
});
```

Comment: I think at the time of @MathewBerg answer the OP comment clarifying different array length behavior was not there. The result is common in SO: Scattered up votes w/o clear differentiation, a flurry of disorganized commentary like everybody talking at once - who is replying to whom? Asking the question is harder than answering it.

Comment: @radarbob Yeah. OP should have clarified that from the begining. I'll notify @ mathewBerg of the change.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just loop over both arrays?

```
$scope.merged = [];
for(var x = 0; x < $scope.links.length && x < $scope.colors.length; x++){
    $scope.merged.push(Object.assign({}, $scope.links[x], $scope.colors[x]));
}
```

Comment: Heads up! There seems to be a [**change**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50336622/revisions) to the question.